# Bootstrap Glyphicons not showing in Cakephp

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePhp 3.4.7 and Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Bootstrap is working fine except that Glyphicons are not showing. Here's what my Login page looks like and you can see the icons are missing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiA7Q.jpg

I placed all the glyphicons-halflings-regular.* fonts in the App/webroot/font directory and the bootsrap.min.css in App/webroot/css and bootsrap.min.js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js in App/webroot/js

And inspecting my website I can see both css and js files are being pulled correctly and in fact the code is working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogQdJ.jpg

Here is my code

**DEFAULT CTP HEAD**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>
    <?= $cakeDescription ?>:
    <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
</title>
<?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>

<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery-3.2.1.min.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js') ?>

<?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
<?= $this->fetch('css') ?>
<?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
</head>
```

**LOGINT CTP**

```
<?
// Path File: \App\src\Templates\Usuarios\login.ctp
/** @var $this \Cake\View\View */
?>
<div class="container alto-minimo-contenido">
    <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> &nbsp;Formulario de ingreso al sistema</div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">
                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
                <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->Url->build(["controller" => "Usuarios", "action" => "login"]) ?>">
                    <label for="login-username">E-Mail</label>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail">
                    </div>
                    <label for="login-password">Clave</label>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Clave">
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-push-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-pull-1 controls">
                            <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> ENTRAR</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see that in my bootstrap.min.css files the path is correct. Any idea why Cake is not pulling the icons even though they exist?

Comment: Open your browsers network console and check what the requests and responses for the fonts files look like.

Comment: you wouldn't know if the files are being pulled or not by looking at the source code/DOM structure(they will just show what you have given). Looking under the "Console" tab would give you more details on the errors. Considering your situation i'm sure there are few path issues showing up there

Comment: You are both correct: When I inspected the code I can see a 404 error for these font files. Why is cake not being able to pull the fonts if they are present in the default folder i.e. App/webroot/fonts?

Comment: Looking at the bootstrap.min.css I can see the path as url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') which is fine since the font and css directories are at the same level within App/webroot

Comment: In case that isn't just a typo in the examples that your showing, your folder structure in the question says `font`, and the CSS URL says `fonts`.

Comment: It was just a typo, however I got it resolved after deleting all the content in the tmp folder of my project. Should this be happening? Not sure, but after deleting the folder and cleaning the browser information it worked. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your CSS folder.
2. Open the bootstrap.min.css file.
3. Search for glyphicon text in that.
4. You can find out its url address.
5. You should change the font folder name to fonts.
6. Go and enjoy your life. :)

Comment: I got it resolved after deleting all the content in the tmp folder of my project. Should this be happening? Not sure, but after deleting the folder and cleaning the browser information it worked. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Oh yeah, caching is a pain...  It was resolved before, it just kept spitting up the wrong stuff, don't worry about it.  Next time, change the log level a couple times and it'll clear all that out, when you're debugging something mysterious like this.